# tfs does not have "Mock debug" configuration

Tags: visual-c++, tfs

I am trying to build a solution that has 3 projects. The solution configuration is Debug| Win32. On the solution configuration properties, for the projects: 
Project      Configuration   Platform
1st project: Mock Debug       Win32
2nd Project: Debug            Win32
and same goes for third.The build is failing because of the First project with Configuration Mock Debug.
The error throws LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file $(Configuration)....
When I build on VS2012 it builds fine. It creates a folder "Mock Debug" and places the lib there. And VS can find the lib. No problem, build successful. 
But in tfs I cannot specify configuration "Mock debug" so it does not create the folder "Mock Debug" and does not place the .lib. there. I cannot change any of the solution configuration or the project property. Is there any way to specify exact configurations for the individual projects build under the solution in the tfs build definition. I know I can pass MsBuild Argument in build definito but I am not sure if that will work. I tried specifying "Mock Debug" configurations manually, under "items to build" and "configuration to build". But it does not find "Mock Debug" configuration. I found out team build does override $OutDir specified in the project and places all binaries somewhere else hence it cannot find the .lib file. But the problem is The Folder specified by $(Configuration) "Mock Debug" is not created. I think I am missing something here....any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Just put such a configuration or dll in the following path on the building machine

*"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies"*

**Note**: you many need change the bath depend on the VS version you are using.